# Function with XML path doesnt work

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a function that concat field from different row and  group by id.
When I execute my code in TSql is work fine, But when I execute  it as a function it returns wrong data, Why?

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable ([ID] INT, [Name] CHAR(1), [Value] INT)

INSERT INTO YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (1,'A',4)
INSERT INTO YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (1,'B',8)
INSERT INTO YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (2,'C',9)
INSERT INTO YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (3,'d',9)
INSERT INTO YourTable ([ID],[Name],[Value]) VALUES (3,'u',9)

SELECT 
    [ID],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [Name] 
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM YourTable Results
GROUP BY id;
```

```
create     FUNCTION dbo.CONCAT_String_group_by_id (@id int , @name varchar    
(100) )
RETURNS TABLE AS return
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT @id id ,@name name
    FROM (VALUES(0)) a(m))
SELECT 
    [ID],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [Name] 
        FROM cte 
        WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM cte Results
GROUP BY id
```

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM YourTable CROSS APPLY dbo.CONCAT_String_group_by_id (id,name) n
```

**First query Output:**

```
ID  NameValues
1   A, B
2   C
3   d, u
```

**Second query Output:**

```
ID  NameValues
1   A
1   B
2   C
3   d
3   u
```

Comment: plus 1 for sample data.could you also add expected and actual results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function wont work ,because Cross apply will be executed for each row of outer query  once and outputs the result

In your first query,you are evaluating all the data at once and logical order of execution goes like below

**query:**

```
SELECT 
    [ID],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [Name] 
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM YourTable Results
GROUP BY id;
```

1.group by id from your table
2.Do a concat of all IDs Present using XML

In your second query ,you are using cross apply **to pass one row at a time** and it will have only one row to concat ,so your output varies

Answer (score 0):

What about this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CONCAT_String_group_by_id (@id int)
RETURNS TABLE AS return
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE id = @id
)
SELECT 
    [ID],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + [Name] 
        FROM cte 
        WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM cte Results
GROUP BY id
```

In your function you have just one row in your CTE (`WITH`) so always you will have one letter in `NameValues`.

Comment: this for specfic table i want to build Generic function